# Different typedef for same information

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I was working on a piece of code and I encountered this :

```
typedef jobject jthread;
typedef jobject jthreadGroup;
```

What is the significance of different typedef for similar entry ?

Comment: No significance. Someone wants to use both `jthread` and `jthreadGroup`, they just happen to be the same type. Perhaps they are different types on some other system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to have two different names for the same type. There are (at least) two different reasons you'd want this:

1. In the code, you want the reader to see what type of data we're dealing with. After all, a "thread" is diffferent from a "group of threads", even if the underlying type representing them are different.
2. Ability to change type for one of the types without affecting the other. If at a later stage, we decide that "jthreadGroup" is better to be a new type, we can change that without affecting "jthread".

Imagine that we have a small game, where we count the score in an integer type. We also have a count of players:

```
typedef int ScoreCount;
typedef int PlayerCount;
```

Later on, we decide that we only need a small number, `short` to count players:

```
typedef short PlayerCount;
```

Same idea as using "jobject", just a different base-type, that possibly make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

May be for acheiving code clarity they typedefed same type in different name
Here you can use both jthread and jthreadGroup instead of jobject type